# highrise api not working with spring

Tags: java, spring, api, highrise

I am trying to use highrise api with my java spring application.

I copied highrise .jar from https://github.com/dnobel/highrise-java-api. But I am getting exception when I run my appliaction with this and it stops my tomcat server

```
   [ERROR] 2013-09-30 12:03:34 Context initialization failed
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with       name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property    'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to  bean     'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0'  while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0':  Cannot resolve reference to bean  'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property  'authenticationManager'; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to     bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0'  while setting constructor argument; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0':  FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean  'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting  constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Error setting  property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException;  nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property ' passwordEncoder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:354)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:587)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

when I remove highrise jar file then my application works fine.

Does anyone has idea why I am getting this error or is there any other way to use highrise api I have got the highrise token number to connect. I want to retrieve all Emails, Notes and deals with employee names.

Please let me know if you need anymore information

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the spring  security libraries in your class path ? 
It seems that your highrise jar file needs security library.